# Getting XPath from Value or Text

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy, selector

I am a beginner & don't know much about scraping.

My question is that can we get XPath of an HTML element from its text or value using any library / tool
Normally the process is done in reverse which works well.
I have used Scrapy & Selenium but not limited to any particular library / framework

For example from:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="class1">text</div>
  </body>
</html>
// above div can be any element which may not even have a class
```

Can we get an output like:

```
//div[@class='class1']
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can construct your own :

```
ele =  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[text()='text']")
class_attr = ele.get_attribute('class')
tag_nam = ele.tag_name
construct_xpath = str("//") + tag_nam + str("[@class='") + class_attr + " '] "
```

Comment: But the reference element "//div[text()='text']" may or may not be a div.
And it may or may not have a class, can be a 3rd <td> in a <tr> for example.

Comment: You need to know the web element if you want to create your own xpath

Comment: I am trying to fetch them dynamically to be used in Machine Learning. With 1000+ websites I don't think it will be possible to know XPaths of all elements in all websites

Comment: @HamzaTasneem : for that matter you can segregate them like a list of divs or a list of spans and so on..

Comment: Why would you write a locator to locate an element and then build another locator for the same element? OP is asking how to quickly find a locator for a given element, not generate a new one from an existing locator.

Comment: @JeffC : Read this from OP `Can we get an output like: //div[@class='class1']` How on earth you would create locators using programs ?

Comment: Use Chrome devtools, right-click on the element, Copy > Copy XPath. Those are terrible locators but if OP doesn't want to learn how to write locators, that's about the only option short of a different tool that does the same thing. I don't think OP knows enough to know what they are asking.

Comment: @JeffC : I agree I think he does not know the complexity of work he asked for. Chrome devtools is not a solution I feel cause you would have lot of issue with same browser as well as with cross browser testing.

Comment: I don't know why would you close the question but the main idea was to;
1) Get locators dynamically using values
2) Put them in a pre-defined template
3) Processing that predefined template should create a static scraper

Comment: @HamzaTasneem : writing locator is a skill, how can you dynamically create a skill ?

Comment: @cruisepandey its a scrapy template, lets suppose price = response.xpath(xpath::attribute)

Comment: `Chrome & selenium do generate those locators` - no they don't. It is Document object model that let us interact with us using locators

Comment: @cruisepandey that's what I wanted to know, some library (chrome through selenuim may be) which may create that opposed to writing down thousand of edge cases.

Comment: What do you mean by edge cases ? You can't generate a stable locator dynamically.. if you just want to generate locator maybe chrome dev tool is best option for you.

Comment: I think I am getting the point now.
But maybe this would work in your experience: html -> pass through Chrome + selenium we get DOM.
DOM -> Given to Some XPath creating Library -> Array of Xpaths?

Comment: I think you don't understand locator at all. How many arrays will you create ? There are more than 8 locators I know of. How would you get to know if any class is dynamic or not ? there are lot of scenarios. It is not impossible to do that but it is dumb to do that :)

Comment: Got it, I just thought it would be something common.